# reload tableView after inserting row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a section header which shows the number of comments. When the user adds a new comment, I call insertRow and want to change the cell that shows the number of comments. The problem is though that any variation of .reloadData ruins the animation. I've tried using CA.commit() with completion set on CAtransaction and reloading just the individual cell. Any ideas how I can reload the data after **both** the insertion and scrolling are complete?

```
let indexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath(row:(self.comments.count - 1), section:3)
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .bottom)
self.tableView.endUpdates()

self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
//I want to call self.tableView.reloadData() here
```

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            //Reload your tableview here
    }

Comment: Rather than using `insertRows` followed by `reloadData`, what happens if you just use `reloadSections`?

Comment: @Paulw11perfect thanks that worked. curious though - why does that work over reloadRow (assuming that section only has 1 row)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code (instead of reloading the whole table, reload just the single one row that contains comments):

```
let indexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath(row:(self.comments.count - 1), section:3)
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .bottom)
// lets try to reload just the cell with comments
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPathOfCellWithComments], with: .fade)
self.tableView.endUpdates()

self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

Moreover, it cannot be seen from the code, but don't forget to update the data so that inserted row has a backing new item in data model.

Answer (score -1):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
       tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanations